# Repeating 'False' outputs

Tags: python, graph, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am trying to implement a dfs to find cycles in a string graph. For example the graph:

```
walkways_info = """\
U 3
0 1
1 2
2 0
"""
```

Would return True. I am currently having the issue that my if statement:

```
if current_vertex in visited or int(graph[i].split()[1]) in visited:
```

It is outputting False but I don't want it to output anything at this stage.

Updated code [Here](http://pastebin.com/6cGVy6zF)

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: I would propose to you building an adjacency matrix based on string representation BEFORE solving any graph-based task. This way you will be able to use well-known and polished algorithms and implementation.

Comment: Look at your code: the only way it can return `False` is when your graph is empty!

Comment: I've added `return False` outside of the for loop shouldn't this trigger if the graph is iterated through and `return True` isn't called?

Comment: I added a print statement at `else: return True` `print(visited)` and visited is a empty list. It must not be entering the `if current_vertex in visited == False` loop but I'm not sure why..

Comment: Bump..................

Comment: Sufficient code to allow a question to be answered needs to be included **in the question itself** to comply with MCVE rules. Links bitrot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have an order of operation error, the `in` and `==` are not playing nicely.

`current_vertex in visited == True` evaluates like this `(current_vertex in (visited == True))`

Example:

```
In [1]: x = [0,1,2]

In [2]: y = 1

In [3]: y in x == True
Out[3]: False

In [3]: y in x
Out[3]: True
```

So if you drop your `== True` it should work.

```
if current_vertex in visited or int(graph[i].split()[1]) in visited:
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for this but I noticed now when it gets to `if current_vertex in visited or int(graph[i].split()[1]) in visited` it will output `False` can I get it to not do this?